# Using Stack Exchange account instead of OpenID

Tags: support, user-accounts, stackexchange, openid

I have signed up in Stack Exchange using an OpenID provider. Now, I want to log in my account using Stack Exchange account. But in the "my logins" page there is no link for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the workaround in [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704) - it involves changing your profile email to the desired address, then using the password reset function to initialise the account.